# Python - Get Inside the Circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to crop everything around a point, but instead the image just expands to fill the area.

[As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr4bn.png)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import utm
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

with cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg') as image_file:
    image = plt.imread(image_file)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

n = 38.102750
e = -121.329939
s = 37.232750
w = -122.428273

cords = [w, e, s, n]

im = ax.imshow(image, extent=(cords))
patch = patches.Circle((-121.868651, 37.713402), radius=250, transform=ax.transData)
im.set_clip_path(patch)

#ax.axis('off')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()

exit()
```

[Trying to get something to the effect of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp2xH.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your radius is much to large, the circle is much bigger than the region determined by `cords`.  Try e.g. `patches.Circle((..., radius=0.25)`.

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you!